# Why is one positive feedback (red) and the other negative feeback (blue)?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, feedback

[image]

The only difference I see between both circuits is the current direction or contribution, but I still don't understand why one is considered positive feedback while the other is negative.

Comment: Hi Diogo, to get a better (perhaps more comprehensive) answer, please add the image source (and ideally context)

Comment: The blue box doesn't say negative feedback

Comment: @tobalt For context, it's from a paper "A 0.0078mm2 3.4mW Wideband Positive-Feedback-Based Noise-Cancelling LNA in 28nm CMOS Exploiting Gm Boosting".

Comment: @user253751 i was told by a professor that it is negative feeback

Comment: Add your comments (if relevant) to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The two FET configurations below behave differently. On the left is a common drain setup, whose output changes in the same direction as the input, hence the name "follower". It has unity voltage gain, and *does not invert*.

On the right is a common source arrangement, with a gain in the hundreds (potentially), but whose output rises when input potential falls, and vice versa. Therefore this configuration inverts the signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frBdy0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your own diagram shows these two circuits combined into a single unit, where the transistor in one effectively replaces the resistor in the other. The resulting "totem pole" arrangement has an output at the junction between the two transistors, but the inverting or non-inverting nature of each element has not changed. That is, one of the pair of transistors will attempt to *raise* the output potential in response to a rise in gate potential, while the other tries to *lower* the output for that same change in input, exactly as they did when they were alone with their resistor.

Whatever feedback from their mutual output is applied back to their gates, for one of them that feedback is positive and for the other it's negative, due to that asymmetry.

The red box in your circuit encapsulates the common-source half, which inverts. Feedback to its gate is *also* inverted (−A) so changes in the output result in the transistor further forcing the output *in the same direction*. Thus net feedback is positive for that transistor.

By contrast, the upper transistor acts as a source follower, not inverting, but its feedback *is* inverted, so you can consider that feedback to be negative from the perspective of that particular FET.

Comment: `Feedback to its gate is also inverted (−A)` ... if A is positive.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a great explanation.

Comment: @tobalt I assume that A is positive, because that's the only way I imagine that the red box could legitimately be labelled "positive feedback", but it sure is an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The positive feedback comes from \$M_{BIAS}\$ and the negative feedback comes from \$M1\$.

When the input signal rises, node-X voltage also rises and, due to the inverting amplifier, \$M_{BIAS}\$ turns-off more thus allowing X to rise more. This is positive feedback.

However, for the same situation as X rising, M1 also turns-off more and this is negative feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the voltage at node X.

Now increase it slightly. The red circuit will increase it more, whereas the blue circuit will counteract the increase.

This is because the red circuit has a positive loop gain, while the blue circuit has a negative loop gain.

---

*This is all assuming that **-A<0**.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it. The current increase results in a larger voltage drop from vcc to m1's source, lowering it. On the other hand, a larger voltage drop from the mbias' drain to vee increases the previous.